# Advanced search for java code

Tags: java, refactoring

Is there any easy way to get advanced search in Java code? I'm migrating our application from Glassfish 2 to Glassfish 4. Few libraries changed their way of handling inputs and I would like find where this specific situations will occur.

For example:
JPA 1.2

```
MyEntity some = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, 1234);
some.setIdMyEntity(null);
entityManager.persist(some);
```

Code similar to this above was working in a way it persisted new entity with new auto generated id (if appropriate annotation was in entity).

JPA 2.2
The same code will produce error

```
The attribute [idMyEntity] of class [my.package.MyEntity] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.
```

I understand reasons behind this change and I would like to fix my application and find places which need fix as precisely as it is possible.

To find these I used regular expression `\.setId[a-zA-Z]+\(null\);` However there are hundreds or even thousands of matches and 90% are false positives. That's why I would search engine which could do something like that:

```
Look for invocation of setter (which is related to field annotated as @Id) 
with argument null on object which is instance of class annotated as @Entity
```

As I told this is only example so basically what I'm looking for are ways of advanced searching in Java code.
Anything more than dead simple search/ regular expression search/ find usages capabilities are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Intellij IDEA Structural Search https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html

Comment: It looks very promising I will give a try to IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Easy? You might consider our [Source Code Search Engine (SCSE)](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine/).

This lets you write queries using the syntax of the target language (in this case, Java) which helps to cut false positives.   You might write a query like:

```
 '.' I=setID* '(' ... 'null' ... ')' ';'
```

which will match only code of that shape; in particular, it will ignore comments/Javadoc and strings that accidentally look like this.  So some interesting fraction of your false positives will go away.  This is easy to set up in minutes and execute.

Not so easy: The hard part about doing your query "right" is that you want to know *semantic* properties of the code, which no pure syntax-driven tool (e.g., grap, SCSE) can do.

For the latter, you need a tool that parses and name-resolves the Java, and makes the properties available to the matching checks.

To achieve that effect,  you could use our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine/) with its full Java front end. DMS
lets you write patterns that match the exact syntax (no false positive errors on this part) and consult additional semantic properties
as an additional matching condition (see "if" below).

You'd have to write a bit of custom code to check for the specific
semantic properties, but with that you could write a DMS pattern match:

```
     pattern null_setter(p: access_path): statement =
          " \p ( null ) ; "
     if is_setter_annotated(p,"Id") /\ is_parameter_annotated(p,"Entity");
```

where the "is_setter_annotated" and "is_parameter_annotated" are the custome functions that take the syntax tree matched for p, look it up in the symbol tables provided by the Java front end, and checks those properties. 
You might need several patterns, if your setters might take multiple arguments one of which is the interesting null.

The "is_setter_annotated" check is likely to be a bit difficult to write, because it has to inspect the possibly nontrivial code of the body of p to find an assignment to a field that has been appropriately annotated.   One can do that by writing additional patterns (likely several) to check various kinds of assignments, something like the following:

```
    pattern is_annotated_field_assignment(i: identifier, e:expression): statement
       " \i = \e ; "
    if is_annotated(i);
```

If you were lazy, you could skip the latter at the price of false positives for things function calls on methods which are not setters, your choice.

If ithere are only "(some) hundreds"... of possible false positives,  using DMS isn't worth the effort; as ugly as it sounds, you can cross your eyes and just slog through your regexp results.  If it is thousands, it is likely worth the trouble.   And you might be able to write a mechanical program transformation (DMS supports this) that could find and *patch* the broken locations, if the fix is regular in style.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how many false positive you're getting but I suspect you'd better run your search / replace regex and go through the whole changelist to see if it really needs to be changed. I am sure you will be able to quickly undo changes by packages, etc.
I always find this approach faster than to do a blind search then identify if this is correct code to change then change it.

Alternatively, you could use Eclipse JDT to fix the code, but I do not recommend it to you. Automating code transformations is never as easy as it sounds even when you're used to the JDT APIs, and I suspect you do not know these APIS.

Comment: By Java Development Tools name I would expect that I have to write code to do my transformation or search. I believe that's too much work for my issue. However thank you for this clue.